# How to run a functionality after login in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a "add to wish" list link.

when the user clicks on it, the application should check whether the user is logged in or not:

1. If user logged in, the product get added in wish list and it get redirected to wish list page.
2. If the user isn't logged in, it should be shown the login form on popup over there and asked to login. After user is logged in, the user should reach the wish list page after automatically adding the product in wish list.

Can anyone suggest me the way this can be done in Laravel?

Comment: provide some code so that some one will help

Answer (score 1):

I do similar functionality with a shopping cart.

I create the cart, fill the product. Unless the user is logged in, I just have the `cart_id` stored in `session`.

Then after the user logs in, I check the `session` if there is a cart created I update the cart with the `user_id` and display the same products.

So this will be the same approach I would've taken with wishlist. 
Let me know if it helps.